# How to traverse a typed array?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the following class model in my application Angular:

```
export class IItemsModel {
  public description: string;
  public itemDetail: IItemDetailModel;
  public itemCategories: IItemCategoriesModel[];  // array of IItemCategoriesModel
}

export class IItemCategoriesModel {
  public id: string | number;
  public description: string;
}
```

And my Controller:

```
itemModel: IItemsModel;
selectedCategories: any[] = [];

ngOnInit() {
  this.itemModel = new IItemsModel();
  this.itemModel.itemCategories = [];
}

onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
  // here I format the data
}
```

In the template I have a multiple select where I fill an `array` with the id's of the chosen categories.

```
[25, 38]  // selectedCategories
```

Problem, I'm using **ngModel** to link the form with the controler, but to send the pre-filled data to the API, I have to format the id's to the model format, that is:

```
{
  ...,
  itemDetail: 'something',
  itemCategories: [
    { id: any Id },
    { id: other Id }
  ]
}
```

I try to format the data as follows in the **`onSubmit()`** method:

```
for(let i=0; i<this.selectedCategories.length; i++) {
  this.itemModel.itemCategories[i].id = this.selectedCategories[i];
}
```

But I get the error:

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'id' of undefined @ undefined:undefined

How could you be formatting the itemCategories to be able to send the data correctly to the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `forEach` to iterate instead of `for` loop.

```
this.selectedCategories.forEach(f => {
    this.itemModel.itemCategories.push({ id: f, description: '' })
});
```

Since your `selectedCategories` object is an array of numbers, it doesn't have `id` property in it. That's why you're getting errors.

**Working demo** at [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m3dhjl?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

**Click the button and check the console log.**